# How do I avoid a strong class to affect the entire website?

Tags: html, css

I copied this CSS

```
body
{
    background: #eee; /* For visibility of elements. */
}
p.box.info {
    background: #DEEFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    color: #004AAD;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 2rem;
}
strong {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 27px;
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    p.box.info {
        animation-duration: 0s !important;
        transition-duration: 0s !important;
    }
    strong {
        animation-duration: 0s !important;
        transition-duration: 0s !important;
    }
}
```

to style a box like this:
[image: Box]

The problem now is that every time I bold a word outside that box, it seems to be applying that CSS. Should I give the strong inside that custom CSS a different name? Like strong.box to avoid this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's because of strong {} css. if you write this css all of the stron tag in the html is affected

Comment: `p.box.info strong`. Please check CSS basics.